# Simple image processing algorithm causes Processing to freeze

Tags: image, memory, processing

I've written an algorithm in Processing to do the following:

```
1. Instantiate a 94 x 2 int array
2. Load a jpg image of dimensions 500 x 500 pixels
3. Iterate over every pixel in the image and determine whether it is black or white then change a variable related to the array
4. Print the contents of the array
```

For some reason this algorithm freezes immediately. I've put print statements in that show me that it freezes before even attempting to load the image. This is especially confusing to me in light of the fact that I have written another very similar algorithm that executes without complications. The other algorithm reads an image, averages the color of each tile of whatever size is specified, and then prints rectangles over the region that was averaged with the average color, effectively pixelating the image. Both algorithms load an image and examine each of its pixels. The one in question is mostly different in that it doesn't draw anything. I was going to say that it was different for having an array but the pixelation algorithm holds all of the colors in a color array which should take up far more space than the int array.

From looking in my mac's console.app I see that there was originally this error: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded". From other suggestions/sources on the web I tried bumping the memory allocation from 256mb to 4000mb (doing this felt meaningless because my analysis of the algorithms showed they should be the same complexity but I tried anyways). This did not stop freezing but changed the error to a combination of "JavaNativeFoundation error occurred obtaining Java exception description" and "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".
Then I tried pointing processing to my local jdk with the hope of utilizing the 64 bit jdk over processing's built in 32 bit jdk. From within Processing.app/Contents I executed the following commands:
mv Java java-old
ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk Java
Processing would not start after this attempt with the following error populating my console: 
"com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (org.processing.app.160672[13559]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1"

Below is my code:
First the noncompliant algorithm

```java
int squareSize=50;
int numRows = 10;
int numCols = 10;
PFont myFont;
PImage img;

//33-126
void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  count();
}

void count(){
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  int[][] asciiArea = new int[94][2];
  println("hello?");
  img=loadImage("countingPicture.jpg");
  println("image loaded");
  for(int i=0; i<(500/squareSize); i++){
    for(int j=0; j<(500/squareSize); j++){
      int currentValue=i+j*numCols;
      if(currentValue+33>126){
        break;
      }
      println(i+", "+j);
      asciiArea[currentValue][0]=currentValue+33;
      asciiArea[currentValue][1]=determineTextArea(i,j,squareSize);
      //fill(color(255,0,0));
      //ellipse(i*squareSize,j*squareSize,3,3);
    }
  }
  println("done calculating");
  displayArrayContents(asciiArea);
}

int determineTextArea(int i, int j, int squareSize){
  int textArea = 0;
  double n=0.0;
  while(n < squareSize*squareSize){
    n+=1.0;
    int xOffset = (int)(n%((double)squareSize));
    int yOffset = (int)(n/((double)squareSize));
    color c = img.get(i*squareSize+xOffset, j*squareSize+yOffset);
    if(red(c)!=255 || green(c)!=255 || blue(c)!=255){
      println(red(c)+" "+green(c)+" "+blue(c));
      textArea++;        
    }    
  }
  return textArea;
}

void displayArrayContents(int[][] arr){
  int i=0;
  println("\n now arrays");
  while(i<94){
    println(arr[i][0]+" "+arr[i][1]);
  }
}
```

The pixelation algorithm that works:

```java
PImage img;
int direction = 1;
float signal;
int squareSize = 5;
int wideness = 500;
int highness = 420;
int xDimension = wideness/squareSize;
int yDimension= highness/squareSize;

void setup() {
  size(1500, 420);
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  frameRate(30);
  img = loadImage("imageIn.jpg");
  color[][] colors = new color[xDimension][yDimension];
  for(int drawingNo=0; drawingNo < 3; drawingNo++){
  for(int i=0; i<xDimension; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<yDimension; j++){
      double average = 0;
      double n=0.0;
      while(n < squareSize*squareSize){
        n+=1.0;
        int xOffset = (int)(n%((double)squareSize));
        int yOffset = (int)(n/((double)squareSize));
        color c = img.get(i*squareSize+xOffset, j*squareSize+yOffset);
        float cube = red(c)*red(c) + green(c)*green(c) + blue(c)*blue(c);
        double grayValue = (int)(sqrt(cube)*(255.0/441.0));
        double nAsDouble = (double)n;
        average=(grayValue + (n-1.0)*average)/n;
        average=(grayValue/n)+((n-1.0)/(n))*average;
      }
      //average=discretize(average);
      println(i+" "+j+" "+average);
      colors[i][j]=color((int)average);
      fill(colors[i][j]);
      if(drawingNo==0){ //stroke(colors[i][j]); }
      stroke(210);}
      if(drawingNo==1){ stroke(150);  }
      if(drawingNo==2){ stroke(90); }
      //stroke(colors[i][j]);
      rect(drawingNo*wideness+i*squareSize,j*squareSize,squareSize,squareSize);
    }
  }
  }
  save("imageOut.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're entering an infinite loop, which makes the `println()` statements unreliable. Fix the infinite loop, and your print statements will work again.

Look at this `while` loop:

```
while(i<94){
    println(arr[i][0]+" "+arr[i][1]);
}
```

When will `i` ever become `>=` 94?

You never increment `i`, so its value is always `0`. You can prove this by adding a `println()` statement inside the `while` loop:

```
while(i<94){
    println("i: " + i);
    println(arr[i][0]+" "+arr[i][1]);
}
```

You probably wanted to increment `i` inside the `while` loop. Or just use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: Yikes! How embarassing. Good catch and thank you. Still though, I don't understand why it wouldn't print the statements before the infinite loop. Could you shed some more insight on that?

Comment: @AustinWehn I'm not totally sure myself. But Processing doesn't handle infinite loops very well in general (the entire editor freezes up), so I'm not very surprised that `println()` doesn't work very well either.

Comment: Thank you @KevinWorkman. One other thing, do you have any experience using Processing in a mode where you can debug? I think I saw something about running it through Eclipse but am wondering if it is worth the hassle. Kind of surprised that Processing doesn't have debugging to begin with.

Comment: @AustinWehn Yeah, I have experience running Processing through eclipse. But Processing does have a debugger built into the editor- it's the little butterfly button in the upper-left corner, right next to the mode dropdown.